# Openshift: view file system

Tags: file, openshift, system

i'm new to Openshift. 
Here my problem: 
i've deployed a war, using git and it works fine. I have a servlet that upload images, and everything is okay. 
I don't understand, where should I go to see the structure file system. 
For example, in Tomcat in eclipse I can see the uploaded file in the file system. 
Is there the chance in openshift to see my file system and so my uploaded file? 
And more, if I deploy a war, may I have the chance to modify it with some kind of console in openshift? 
Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is using rhc client.
So these are the steps to follow:

1) install ruby-installer
2) install git
3) install rhc
4) type rhc setup.

Then you will be asked to input your credentials. Once logged in, you will obtain an OAuth token, and a new public key is uploaded to openshift.

Then type:

rhc -a app_nome and you will have the app view.
Then, typing ls, you will see the entire file system.